# Retaining maximum of a vector into another vector in R

Tags: r

I want to retain the maximum value in a vector. R code is written below.
How to fix this code so it runs without errors?

dat is in a data frame

```
dat=c(3, 5, 4, 2, 8, NA, NA, 9, 10, 3)
```

desired output is
    MaxRuns=c(3,5,5,5,8,8,8,9,10,10)

```
maxValue=function(dat){
maxv=0
for (i in 1:10) MaxRuns(i)=0
for (i in 1:10){
if dat(i) > maxv {
maxv=dat(i) }
MaxRuns(i)=maxv
 }
return(maxv)
}
maxValue<-maxValue(dat)
maxValue
```

Errors:

> dat=c(3,  5,  4,  2,  8, NA, NA,  9, 10,  3)

```
>     maxValue=function(dat){
+     maxv=0
+     for (i in 1:10) MaxRuns(i)=0
+     for (i in 1:10){
+     if dat(i) > maxv {
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    for (i in 1:10){
    if dat"
>     maxv=dat(i) }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    maxv=dat(i) }"
>     MaxRuns(i)=maxv
Error: object 'maxv' not found
>      }
Error: unexpected '}' in "     }"
>     return(maxv)
Error: object 'maxv' not found
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>     maxValue<-maxValue(dat)
Error in maxValue(dat) : could not find function "maxValue"
>     maxValue
Error: object 'maxValue' not found
```

Thank you. MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to fix.

You can check if an entry is NA by using is.na.  Also, when you access the entries of dat, use dat[i] rather than dat(i). Also, try not to name a varible the variable the same name as a function's name.

```
dat=c(3, 5, 4, 2, 8, NA, NA, 9, 10, 3)
maxValue=function(dat){
    maxv=0
    MaxRuns = rep(0, 10)
    for (i in 1:10){
        if (!is.na(dat[i]) && dat[i] > maxv){
            maxv=dat[i] }
    MaxRuns[i]=maxv
     }
    return(MaxRuns)
}
maxRuns<-maxValue(dat)
print(maxRuns)
```

prints out

```
[1]  3  5  5  5  8  8  8  9 10 10
```

Comment: Interesting that I need to use rep function rather than two instances of for (i in 1:10). Was something wrong with my syntax? Otherwise, I am definitely going to keep this one around.  Thank you. MM

Comment: I didn't define MaxRuns earlier, hence I define it there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `cummax` but you need to handle `NA`s. As `dat` is completely positive replacing `NA`s with 0 here.

```
cummax(replace(dat, is.na(dat), 0))
#[1]  3  5  5  5  8  8  8  9 10 10
```

As mentioned by @Dason, replacing the `NA` values with `min` would make it general

```
cummax(replace(dat, is.na(dat), min(dat, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

You can access each element of vector using square brackets (`[]`) and not round brackets (`()`). I would write a loop something like this.

```
maxv = integer(length = length(dat))
current_max = 0

for (i in seq_along(dat)) {
  if (dat[i] > current_max & !is.na(dat[i])){
     current_max <- dat[i]
  }
  maxv[i] <- current_max
}

maxv
#[1]  3  5  5  5  8  8  8  9 10 10
```

Comment: Replacing with the min of the vector would keep it more general

Comment: @Dason yes, correct. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.